# Failed because: Invalid action error in Cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am encountering the following error message when capturing a photo using the Camera plugin for Cordova:

"Failed because: Invalid action"

I have tried debugging this error but I am not sure what could be causing it and am running out of ideas!

The tablet device I am testing on is running Android 4.4.4 (Nexus 7).

The strange thing is that I do not get this error when choosing a photo from the gallery, only when using the device camera. My gut feeling is that something in a recent update has changed.

Here is the code I am using for the camera functionality:

```
/**
     * Take a picture with the camera
     */
    capturePhoto: function() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(PHONEGAP.onPhotoDataSuccess, PHONEGAP.onFail, {
            quality: 50,
            targetWidth: parseFloat($(window).outerWidth() * 1.25),
            targetHeight: parseFloat($(window).outerHeight() * 1.25),
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
            correctOrientation: true,
            allowEdit: true,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
        });

        navigator.camera.cleanup(onSuccess, onFail);

        function onSuccess() {
            console.log("Camera cleanup success.");
        }

        function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }
    },
```

Many thanks in advance!
Ben

Comment: how you added the camera plugin?

Comment: Yes the camera plugin is installed. The camera app opens and I can capture the picture but when the 'accept' button is pressed I get this error and it resorts to the onFail function. I have tried reinstalling the plugin and the android platform.

Comment: can you try by giving some fix value instead of 'targetWidth: parseFloat($(window).outerWidth() * 1.25),' in both width & height

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I set the values to 1024 just to test but same issue occurs

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR;

On Android it's cleaned up anyway after taking a picture in the native code calls.

---

## What the documentations says

The documentation states that the `.cleanup()` call is only supported on iOS.

Both, on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) and the [Cordova Apache Website](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera).

So is there no cleanup on android?
Answer: It is.

---

## What really happens

### JavaScript

If you check the JS bridge to the native world, you can see, it is not checked if it should not call the cleanup for Android. So he is delegating the call to every platform (therefore android, too).

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/www/Camera.js#L182

```
cameraExport.cleanup = function (successCallback, errorCallback) {
    exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'Camera', 'cleanup', []);
};
```

---

### Objective C

On iOS you need to call the JS method yourself, to get the cleanup executed:
(it is not called anywhere else in the Obj C code)

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/ios/CDVCamera.m#L303

```
- (void)cleanup:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    // ...
}
```

---

### Java

On Android the `exec` method only checks for `takePicture`.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/android/CameraLauncher.java#L142 and returns false in case of something other.

[Android Plugin Development](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html)

> Any other action returns false and results in an INVALID_ACTION error, which translates to an error callback invoked on the JavaScript side.

There is still a [cleanup method](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/android/CameraLauncher.java#L1192) which is called [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/android/CameraLauncher.java#L601)

```
private void processResultFromCamera(int destType, Intent intent) throws IOException {
    ...
    this.cleanup(FILE_URI, this.imageUri.getFileUri(), galleryUri, bitmap);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue appeared to be with the `navigator.camera.cleanup` function.

I have removed this and the camera is now working as expected.

Comment: What does that mean?  "I have removed this"?  You deleted the property `cleanup` from the `navigator.camera` object? You removed the plugin (?!).  What was your solution?